# Build tensorflow faster from source for contribution purposes

Tags: tensorflow, build, compilation, bazel

I am building `tensorflow` with `bazel` on my local PC, but as expected it takes quite a long time. The problem is that I want to make my own contributions in the source, so it's not feasible to compile all over again the whole code for every small change that I am making. I want to use tensorflow for a custom project of mine, thus I cannot rely/expect on/from the community to take any issues of mine into consideration.

1. Are there certain targets I may could use with `bazel`, just like if I was using `make`?
2. I have access to a pretty good GPU server but I cannot figure out whether `tensorflow-bazel` uses GPU resources for building. Are there any configurations I could use for building with GPU?
3. What's the fastest way to re-compile `tensorflow`  in general all over again, for every small tweak that I am applying?

How do independent contributors work on `tensorflow` in general?

Answer (score 1):

Bazel is smart about incremental changes. If you change a single file, then only bare minimum will be recompiled. Just change a file and run the same command as you do for a full build

> I have access to a pretty good GPU server but I cannot figure out whether tensorflow-bazel uses GPU resources for building. Are there any configurations I could use for building with GPU?

No, compilers are complicated beasts, which use only CPU

Answer (score 0):

If you want to contribute to Tensorflow go through [Contribution guidelines](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#contribution-guidelines).